# Remove a index from JSON array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a JSON array/model that outputs like so:

```
var jsonArray = 
[0]
[1]
...
[x]
[anotherArray][0]
              [1]
              ...
              [e]
```

I need to save an array without the index of anotherArray in it. A splice, reduce, filter or something else might work? I need the arrays of [0] to [x] in it's own array.

Comment: can you please add some actual array?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to filter all array-type elements then you can just check each element if it's an array or not:

```
const filteredArray = jsonArray.filter(x => !Array.isArray(x))
```

Comment: Thanks i knew it was something simple just stuck for a second